# Load an embedded pdf from a file stream .NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html

I want to create a object html5 element from a file stream instead a pdf file.

I use this with a pdf document from file system and works ok:

```
<body>
     <object id="exPDF" type="application/pdf" data="doc.pdf" width="100%"  eight="500" />
</body>
```

But I want to do it by setting "data" attribute from a file stream into a "Tempdata" (MVC3) or a javascript function or some alternative method:

```
<body>
     <object id="exPDF" type="application/pdf" data="STREAM" />
</body>
```

or

```
<body>
     <object id="exPDF" type="application/pdf" data="javascript:getPdf();" />
</body>
```

Is that posible?
Otherwise... Is there any other way to load an embedded pdf from a stream, or to HttpResponse?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find any solution ? is so could you Please share...

Answer (score 0):

You really should have some `HttpHandler` or `Controller` stream the content using a URL. It's not a good idea to bloat the HTML with that much byte data.

Comment: Yes, I also tried with a controller action. (fileresult and file streamresult) but not works